# python: calculate with specific list elements

Tags: python, list, append

I am quite new to python and I want to create a program which calculates prime numbers. For it to be more efficient I need to save prime numbers and use them to calculate the new ones. I have simplified this code since the other parts are irrelevant to the question.

I used java script before and I'd like to have this expression:

```
primnumb = [1,3,5,7,11 ... ]

if (number % primnumb[i]) != 0:
primnumb.append(number)
```

The problem is that I can't calculate with the number which "primnumb[i]" gives me.

I've been looking around but the

```
for i in primnumb
```

Doesn't make a lot of sense to me since I can't get one specific element from the list.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the list with some prime numbers and then 
check for the others.
I have initialized the list of prime numbers with 2,3,5 and 7 hence I start the range from 8.

Code :

```
primnumbers = [2,3,5,7]

for i in range (8,100):

    flag = True

    for items in primnumbers:

        if i % items == 0:

            flag = False

    if (flag):

        primnumbers.append(i)

print primnumbers
```

Comment: It works a lot different than I thought it would but I think I got it! Thank you!

Comment: I just used this method and came across two other things:
How do I "tell" him to only check items which are smaller than the square root of i? If I add " or i**0.5 > items:" to the "if i % items == 0" it doesn't really work...

Second thing would be more general, is there a method to only get one specific item from a list, without using the "for i in range()" phrase?

Comment: Also, I just checked the code: I used `print("items= " + str(items))` after `for items in primnumbers:` and used `print("check")` everytime the flag is true. What happens is, that it this pattern appears: 2, check, 2,3,2,3,check,2,3,5,2,3,5,check.... **it seems to always repeat the list twice, which would slow the program down by a lot**...

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to have prime numbers up to N in an efficient way.

I am using [sieve](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sieve-in-c++/answer/Ankit-Vallecha) to calculate primes as follows:

```
import math
N = 100
flag = [0]*(N+1)
# tells whether a number is prime or not, like flag[i]=0 means i is prime other wise not
primes = []
#list of prime numbers is primes

for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(N))+1): 
    if( flag[i] == 0 ): # means i number is prime
       for j in range(2*i, N+1, i):
          flag[j] = 1  # sets multiple of i as non prime
for i in range(2, N+1):
    if( flag[i] == 0):
       primes.append(i)

print primes
```